# Why does this code work with a less than sign when the question requests for a greater than sign (nested selects from SQL zoo)?

Tags: sql

(updated) I'm trying to learn SQL from the following website:
https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Nested_SELECT_Quiz

In this quiz, the second question asks to find countries belonging to regions with all populations over 50000 -

It says that this is the correct answer:

SELECT name,region,population FROM bbc x WHERE 50000 < ALL (SELECT population FROM bbc y WHERE x.region=y.region AND y.population>0)

Thats the answer it gives me. Can anyone explain in plain English why this works? If we're looking for population over 50,000 why is the code using a less than sign? And how do nested selects work in general then?

Comment: Why would this not work? the sub-select is returning all populations where `x.region = y.region` and `y.population` is greater than 0. The top level `WHERE` says 50,000 needs to be less than whatever population is returned by the sub-select. I'll admit, it seems like a very odd way to write this.

Comment: If you want to use the qualifier `all` then you need that on the right side of the comparison which means you have to reverse/flip it.

Answer (score 2):

Order matters. `50000 < population` is the same as `population > 50000`.

Why write it this funny way? Because you have to.

Specifically `all` is a [quantified comparison predicate](https://jakewheat.github.io/sql-overview/sql-2016-foundation-grammar.html#quantified-comparison-predicate) and it *must* be of the form `<value> <operator> all(<subquery>)`. So `50000 < all(subquery)`. I can't say why it cannot be reversed, possibly to make parsing this special case easier.

> And how do nested selects work in general then?

[`all`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_all.asp) is true if every row of the subquery meets the condition. `50000 < all(subquery)` means that 50,000 is less than every row in the subquery (or every row in the subquery is over 50000).

```
SELECT name,region,population
FROM bbc x
WHERE 50000 < ALL (
  SELECT population
  FROM bbc y
  WHERE x.region=y.region AND y.population>0
)
```

The subquery runs once for each row in `bbc`. `x` is the `bbc` table in the original query and `y` is the `bbc` table in the subquery. `where x.region=y.region` filters the subquery results to only rows in the same region as the original row.

Comment: Got it, so what could be another way to write this?

SELECT name,region,population FROM bbc x WHERE ALL (SELECT population FROM bbc y WHERE x.region=y.region AND y.population>0) > 50000

Is that valid?

Comment: They might be semantically equivalent but I don't think they're syntactically equivalent: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=869de6176cfbb1a525df71c42478240e

Comment: @shawnt00 You're right, it's a restriction in the SQL grammar. I will fix.

Comment: @diorG I'm wrong, the SQL grammar restricts how it works. I'll fix my answer.